# How to fix Request failed with status code 400 AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: reactjs, axios

I get this error message Request failed with status code 400
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49658:12)
at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48358:66)

can anyone help me to spot where the problem is and how to fix it? here's my code

```
axios.get('https://64dc3b32e64a8526a0f64c9f.mockapi.io/todos'+id)
    .then(res => setData(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[])
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.put('https://64dc3b32e64a8526a0f64c9f.mockapi.io/todos' +id, data)
```

Comment: Seems there is an issue with user id params. Try 'https://64dc3b32e64a8525a0f64c9f.mockapi.io/users/'+id

Comment: tysm! it worked

Comment: A template string is better solution - ``https://64dc3b32e64a8526a0f64c9f.mockapi.io/todos/${id}``